# Class Activity extends ActionBarActivity deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-activity, deprecated

When i create  a new activity it automatically extends ActionBarActivity which is deprecated.
The question is , Do i do something with it? or just leave it alone?

i tried to replace the ActionBarActivity with AppCompatActivity but it gives me errors in the rest of the class.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the errors that you get with the rest of the class?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @orhanC1 The method onCreate(Bundle) of type SexAcivity must override or implement a supertype method AND AppCompatActivity cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @God Is your onCreate `public` or `protected`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i do something with it? or just leave it alone?

Either is fine. If you wish to get rid of the deprecation warning, replace `ActionBarActivity` with `AppCompatActivity`. Hopefully, the new-activity templates will be fixed in an upcoming release of Android Studio.

> i tried to replace the ActionBarActivity with AppCompatActivity but it gives me errors in the rest of the class.

Make sure that you add the `import` statement to import `AppCompatActivity`. [This directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat) contains several sample projects that use `appcompat-v7` and `AppCompatActivity`.

Beyond that, consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide your code and list the errors.

Comment: Thanks man. the import statment did the work. and thanks all the other guys too. i just dont understand why always my question get a negetive vibe in the comunity.

Comment: dont feel bad my questions also get -ve vote ;) it is just your luck which type of students are on their screen when you posted your question :D :/